# Load partial results as initial condition in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am simulating two similar models, say A and B, in Dymola. The only difference between the models A and B is that B does not contain a submodel C.

I have run multiple simulations of model A and everything converges well during the initialization phase. However, I am struggling to simulate model B as it doesn't settle down properly.

My idea was now to take the result of model A as the initial condition for model B. How can I do that, given that model B does not have one of the components of model A?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case "settle down properly" means that model B fails to initialize, you could try to use Dymola's "Save Start Values in Model" function.

Some "how-to" based on the MSL model `Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches`.

1. Simulate the working model
2. In the Simulation ribbon use:
   [image: Calling "Save Start Values in Model"]
3. Set the options for the command, the most important point is that "Store values in a new model" is selected.
   [image: Set options]
4. Dymola will create a new model `CoupledClutchesExt` which extends the original model. The variables selected in the dialog from step 3. will be set. This can help with initialization. The result:

```
model CoupledClutchesExt
  extends Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Examples.CoupledClutches(
    clutch1(mode(start=-1)),
    clutch2(mode(start=2)),
    clutch3(mode(start=2)));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end CoupledClutchesExt;
```

5. In your case you will need to replace the model that is extended (which should be model A) with the model that does not simulate properly (should be model B).

This should transfer the values found for the proper initialization of model A to model B. If that does not help, try to adapt the radio-button selection in the "Advanced" part of the "Save Start Values in Model" dialog. Additionally, you can of course modify the values manually.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your help. However, I am a bit confused about the following error message:
_None of the modified start values could be saved in the model: RH.RV.der(V) Please check model_

Comment: Difficult to say without access to the model. From the variable name the problem could be that the derivative is not a variable in the model and therefore cannot be set during initialization...

Comment: Okay @Markus A., I think I misunderstood your answer. Model B does initialize but crashes after a short time, i.e. it diverges. So, my idea was to use a the output of model A to initialize model B to avoid this divergence. Is it possible to this with your suggested method?

Comment: It is possible, but not guaranteed that it will fix the divergence. It depends on whether there are multiple solutions to the initialization.
But it could also be B is inherently unstable for some reason.